# Factorials/Combinations Yields NaN When Not Supposed To

Tags: javascript, combinations, factorial

I am solving for y Choose p combinations. I am a beginner with Javascript.

I have produced this definition of the factorial function:
It was inteded to do x * (x-1) * (x-2) ... * 1.

```
function factorial(z)
{
    var product = z;
    if (z == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (var m = 1; m < z; m++)
        {
            product = m * product;
            return product;
        }
    }
}
```

I then have this function, which uses the factorial function.

```
function placeBoxes()
{
    var ids = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < (numOfRows-1); y++)
    {
        for (var p = 0; p < (y+1); p++, ids++)
        {
            x = document.createElement('div');
            x.className = "box";
            x.id = ids;
            x.innerHTML = (factorial(y))/((factorial(y-p))*(factorial(p)));
            document.getElementById('holdsBoxes').appendChild(x);
        }
    }
}
```

It is supposed to choose the combinations. For experimental purposes, numOfRows is realistically between 5 and 30. 0C0 1C0 1C1 2C0 2C1 2C2 and so on...
This is equivalent to 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1 and so on...

Does anyone know what I have done wrong? I am getting NaN instead of a value for the second, third, fifth, eighth, ninth, and many other values.

*Edit*: Thank you everyone! The problem is solved. The factorial function was messed up.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var m = 1; m < z; m++)
{
    product = m * product;
    return product;
}
```

Your returning `product` inside your loop. Are you sure about this? Don't you want to return `product` outside your loop?

This is also the cause of your `NaN`. What if `z` is 1 ? then `m < z` is `m < 1` and thats always false. So that loop body is never being called. and the return statement is never called.

So the function returns `undefined`. And `undefined * 1 === NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
    for (var m = 1; m < z; m++)
    {
        product = m * product;
        return product;
    }
```

To

```
    for (var m = 1; m < z; m++)
    {
        product = m * product;
    }
    return product;
```

You're never completing the loop

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the factorial function is incorrect. Try changing it to this:

```
function factorial(z)
{
    var product = z;
    if (z == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (var m = 1; m < z; m++)
        {
            product = product*(product - m);
        }
        return product;
    }
}
```

Comment: `*=` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Also, your previous method of m*product for factorial would work as well - this is just an alternative. The error, as has been pointed out by others as well, is that your return was inside the for loop.